# Add yaml's map to a document using yq

Tags: bash, yaml, yq

I want to add a map (which maps a string to another string, e.g. `fff: bar`) to the following

```yaml
aaa: hello
bbb: world
ccc: foo
```

so I'm using

```bash
document='aaa: hello
bbb: world
ccc: foo'
yq '. = . + {fff: bar}' <<<"$document"
```

but I get **Error: 1:10: invalid input text "fff: bar}**".

If I add a map of numbers, it works

```bash
document='aaa: hello
bbb: world 
ccc: foo' 
yq '. = . + {111: 222}' <<<"$document"
```

outputs

```yaml
aaa: hello
bbb: world
ccc: foo
111: 222
```

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: With [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), you need to quote both strings: `{"fff": "bar"}`. With [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) it's essentially the same but you can leave the key unquoted if it is an identifier-like string: `{fff: "bar"}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add quotes around the `fff` key and value:

```
document='aaa: hello
bbb: world
ccc: foo'
yq '. += {"fff": "bar"}' <<<"$document"
aaa: hello
bbb: world
ccc: foo
fff: bar
➜  ~
➜  ~
```

---

I've also changed `. = . +` to the more readable `. +=`

Answer (score 0):

because the keys in YAML maps must be strings. In your first example, you're trying to add a map with a non-string key ("fff") and a string value ("bar"), which is not valid YAML syntax!

check this out:

```
document='aaa: hello
bbb: world
ccc: foo'
yq '. = . + {"fff": "bar"}' <<<"$document"
```

output :

```
aaa: hello
bbb: world
ccc: foo
fff: bar
```